# I am having problems with formatting razor links in C# MVC, the links are not linking to the css style

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

```
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Finance
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item"> @Html.ActionLink("Account Type", "Index", "AccountTypeTables", null, null) </a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="signup.html">Register</a>
        </div>
    </li>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Your question is not clear.  Please elaborate on what you are trying to ask.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your page contains the css and js:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Finance
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item"> @Html.ActionLink("Account Type", "Index", "AccountTypeTables", null, null) </a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="signup.html">Register</a>
        </div>
</li>
</ul>
@section Scripts{
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
}
```